# How to correctly compare a nodeList against a value in an array of objects, to remove nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a site search which searches two fields that I have merged into one array of objects, I only need to match the "title" value based upon user's input, example of my array (collections.js):

```
export const items = [
{url: '/posts/my-first-post/', title: 'My first post', type: 'Post', id: 'opt-1'},
{url: '/tags/my-first-tag/', title: 'My first tag', type: 'Tag', id: 'opt-2'},
]
```

Then in my main JS file I listen for an 'input' event:

```
import { items } from '/js/collections.js';
const search = document.querySelector('#sFilter');
const searchList = document.querySelector('.search__list');
let arrFiltered = [];
let listNodes;

search.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  if (search.value) {
    search.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
    search.parentElement.setAttribute('data-expanded', 'true');
    filterItems(search.value);
  } else {
    search.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    search.parentElement.setAttribute('data-expanded', 'false');
    searchList.innerHTML = '';
  }
})
```

Then my function is:

```
const filterItems = (term) => {
  arrFiltered = items.filter(item => 
item.title.toLowerCase().trim().includes(term.toLowerCase().trim()));

  arrFiltered.forEach((item, idx) => {
    let res = `<li class="search__item" data-pos="${idx + 1}">
      <a class="search__option" id="${item.id}" href="${item.url}" tabindex="-1">
      <span class="underline">${item.title}</span><span class="search__type">${item.type}</span></a></li>`
    searchList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', res);
  });
  listNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.search__item');

  // Remove DOM nodes not present in `arrFiltered`
}
```

What I am trying to do (unsure if going about it the best way), is:

- Keep the data in the object for looking up (Done)
- Compare the `search.value.toLowerCase().trim()` against the `item.title.toLowerCase().trim()` (Done)
- Add to the `arrFiltered` array (Done)
- Limit that array to a max of 10 results (TODO)
- Compare input value against `item.title`, ignoring punctuation: `(/[\"'..,!?]/g, '')` & `('-', ' ')` (In Progress)
- Create a collection of `<li>` items and append these items to the `searchList` element (Done)
- Remove or add those `<li>` els on subsequent inputs, as opposed to say setting `innerHTML = ''` on every new input event (TODO)

Obviously in my provided code there is no attempt to `remove()` elements from the DOM that don't appear in `arrFiltered` and I know I can set the `innerHTML` as an empty string on each input event, but that's not suitable for this, as "focus" must be maintained on the currently focused element (primarily for screen reader users), if that element is still in the `arrFiltered` array, of course.

An example of my HTML:

```
<ul class="search__list" id="lBox">
  <li class="search__item" data-pos="1">
    <a class="search__option" id="opt-63" href="/posts/my-first-post/" tabindex="-1">
      <span class="underline">My first post</span><span class="search__type">Post</span> 
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="search__item" data-pos="2">
    <a class="search__option" id="opt-64" href="/tags/my-first-tag/" tabindex="-1">
      <span class="underline">My first tag</span><span class="search__type">Tag</span> 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, my question is (finally), I need to `remove()` DOM elements that are no longer in the `arrFiltered` array, so I know I need to use a method that will compare an ID present in the nodeList (the `<li>.firstElementChild.id`) against `item.id` in the `arrFiltered` array, what would be a good way of doing this? I have tried `map()`, `filter()`, `[...spread]` and `Array.from()`, with little success, I'm not saying one or more of those doesn't work, just I'm obviously doing it wrong :/ so i'd be grateful for a little steer. thank you :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, `arrFiltered` is supposed to always have the filtered list of items right? If yes, then why do you want to remove items as relevant items will only be listed as you use only `arrFiltered` to the display as `li` items?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to remove DOM nodes on subsequent keypresses, as the query term changes. So if item.firstElementChild.id is not present in `arrFiltered` anymore, remove that DOM node and any others that should no longer be displayed, as opposed to replacing the whole `<ul>` contents. Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm not inserting the `arrFiltered` array as HTML, I have the `res` variable inside the loop that is doing that. So currently, additional chars in the serach value is just appending the new nodes on top of the nodes that were there before

Comment: To your `items` array, for every object, you can add one more key like `isVisible` and set to true by default. As you filter them, you make the irrelevant ones to false

Comment: *So currently, additional chars in the serach value is just appending the new nodes on top of the nodes that were there before* - This will continue to happen until you flush out previous filter results either through the `isVisible` flag or making `res` to null before passing on recent filter values

Comment: Why not just empty the result list before the `forEach()` loop, and then add the matched results?

Comment: As an example to Hari: arrFiltered.forEach(item => {
    console.log( item.id );
  })

  listNodes.forEach(el => {
    console.log( el.firstElementChild.id );
    // If not in previous loop: el.remove()
  })

Comment: The reason i don't want to clear the `ul` is that a screen reader user may be using the search filter, if I remove the element they are currently "focused" on, then as the "replaced" copy receives "focus" it will be announced, unnecessarily, which is overly verbose. If they are focused on an item and their input removes their currently focused item from the DOM, it is OK to do that, is it is new information, so to speak

Comment: The best way is to create DOM elements instead of HTML string. In this case it would be easy to add el prop in `items` array on the first creation. Then it would be easy to remove elements that are not in current search results. In this case you would not need to find them by ID (or in some other way) in document DOM — you would just have them.